# Elixir: Could not find application file: runtime_tools.app

Tags: docker, elixir

I am using Docker to develop an Elixir umbrella app. I have one umbrella app and inside a Phoenix app. When I start the code locally with `mix phx.server` everything works. When I do the same inside the Docker container (code is synced via `docker-sync`) I get this error:

```
(Mix) Could not start application runtime_tools: could not find application file: runtime_tools.app
```

Any idea on how to fix this?

Comment: My best guess is that I would expect that Erlang is not correctly installed inside your docker. Could you share the Dockerfile?

Comment: erlang-runtime_tools is probably packaged separately on the OS you're running in Docker. Try installing it with the system's package manager.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out erlang-runtime-tools was not installed in my docker image. Adding

```
RUN apk --update add erlang-runtime-tools
```

to the dockerfile fixed the issue. Thanks @Alexei Sholik for pointing this out.